# Win 10/11 Mapped drive set with net command doesn't show in Windows Explorer

Tags: networking, command-line, windows-11

I'm trying to simplify my network mapping experience in Windows.

I'm used to `fstab` in Linux and having to set NAS shares via a file (which I much rather prefer than gui and clicks).  So instead of fumbling through GUIs I was wanting to us a .bat file to set my Mounted shares to my NAS.

Home network, been running forever, setting up a new Windows 11 machine. This is my first Windows 11 machine, but after fussing with mounting via the GUI I'm running into the same fussiness.

Below is some code I've setup to use as a batch file, it runs great, the commands process and I then can access m: and see all of the files in the command prompt. It just doesn't mount in such a way that the m: drive shows up in windows explorer. I'm lost at this point.

```
@echo off
echo 
echo *
echo *
echo ------------------delete drive maps------------------------
net use * /delete /yes
echo ------------------create drive maps------------------------
net use m: \\SERVER\share /user:Username pass
echo -----------------------------------------------------------    
rem EXIT
```

Comment: My experience using SMB between Winbdows and Linux has been that making a desktop shortcut, or a shortcut in the Linux file manager. using full UNC path is more reliable than mounting the remote share as a drive. Yes, a bit of a nuisance.